# Python second level inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm kinda new to python, but I've got a question about second level inheritance.

I have this situation:

```
class A:
  def Something(self):
     #Do Stuff

class B(A):
  def SomethingElse(self):
     #Do other stuff

class C(B):
  def Something(self):
     #Do additional stuff
```

Note that class C inherits from B which inherits from A, but that class B DOES NOT implement method Something().

If I call super(C, self).Something() for an instance of class C, what will happen? Will it call the method from class A?

Additionally, if class B *does* implement Something(), but I want to call class A's Something() directly from class C (ie bypass class B's implementation), how do I do it?

Finally, can someone explain to me why people user super() rather than just calling the parent class's methods directly? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the first case, where B does not implement `Something`, calling `super` will fall up to the place where it is defined, ie `A`.

In the second case, you can bypass B by calling `A.Something(self)`.

The main reason for using `super` is for those cases where you have multiple inheritance: Python will always call the next definition in the MRO (method resolution order).

See Raymond Hettinger's excellent article [Super considered super!](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).

Answer (score 5):

1. Yes, it will call `Something()` from the `A` class.
2. You can always call `A.Something(self)` from `C`.

Explanation for `super()` and other calling conventions would take a while. Have a look at the original article about [MRO](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) and [Python's Super is nifty, but you can't use it](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/).